# jQuery If Statement - fiddle works, website doesn't

Tags: jquery, if-statement, addclass, jsfiddle, removeclass

Alright. I am completely stumped here.

I have a horizontal scrolling list that, when you cannot scroll anymore, the button/arrow changes color (via addClass removeClass). My fiddle works (almost) perfectly. My code on the other hand does not...

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4rKPT/8/

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $item = $('div.mainBodyContentListItem'),
        //Cache your DOM selector
        visible = 2,
        //Set the number of items that will be visible
        index = 0,
        //Starting index
        endIndex = ($item.length / visible) - 1; //End index
    $('div.mainBodyContentArrowR').click(function() {
        if (index < endIndex) { //can scroll
            index++;
            $item.animate({
                'left': '-=592px'
            });
        }
    });

    $('div.mainBodyContentArrowR').click(function() {
        if (index > endIndex) { //can't scroll
            $('div.mainBodyContentArrowR').addClass('disable');
        }
    });

    $('div.mainBodyContentArrowR').click(function() {
        if (index < endIndex) { //can scroll
            $('div.mainBodyContentArrowL').removeClass('disable');
        }
    });



    $('div.mainBodyContentArrowL').click(function() {
        if (index > 0) { //can scroll
            index--;
            $item.animate({
                'left': '+=592px'
            });
        }
    });

    $('div.mainBodyContentArrowL').click(function() {
        if (index < 0) { //can't scroll
            $('div.mainBodyContentArrowL').addClass('disable');
        }
    });

    $('div.mainBodyContentArrowL').click(function() {
        if (index > 0) { //can scroll
            $('div.mainBodyContentArrowR').removeClass('disable');
        }
    });


});
```

This works as it should (except haven't figured out how to fix the issue that going back left and hitting the end of the scroll again, as it was when the page loads, doesn't add the class back and change the color - feel free to address, but it's not the issue of this thread).

My actually code does it correctly in this instance:

```
 $('div.mainBodyContentArrowR').click(function() {
            if (index < endIndex) { //can scroll
                $('div.mainBodyContentArrowL').removeClass('disable');
            }
        });
```

But nowhere else. I am stumped here. The odd thing is, that line I've outlined above is working properly. The 'disable' class is being removed on the first click and then those addClass removeClass lines don't do anything (the scrolling back and forth does work and stop properly).

Please any help is appreciated. I feel like I'm just staring at a 50 foot brick wall and just can't see my way through or over.

Comment: Where does that apply here that my mistake is happening? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change

```
if(index < endIndex)
```

to

```
if(index <= endIndex)
```

Does it work?

The other problem that you have mentioned ( not the topic of this thread should also get fixed if

```
if(index > 0)
```

is changed to

```
if(index >= 1)
```

I knew the problem you mentioned in the comment was coming. To fix that problem you would need to add following line after the line that calculates the end index

```
if(($item.length % visible) == 0){
    enIndex = endIndex - 1;
}
```

Comment: YES~!! And no.... :( Becayse I have to implement this on the horizontal scrolling function of the code, it seems that equation causes it to "overscroll." It needs to stop if there is nothing else there, but it goes that one extra step and animates with nothing to show then disables. But that is still really close. Thank you!

Comment: Added more code. This should fix the problem. Bear with code formatting as I am typing from phone.

Comment: It needs one more line addressing the following line regarding disable scroll left: if (index >= 0). Now that it is allowing = 0, it is enabling the extra scroll (you fixed that going to the right). But if you remove that, it screws with the fix on the addClass item... hmmm... so close. I gotta think about this one.

Comment: Updated the answer again. Changed 0 in the if statement to 1.

Comment: You = The Man. Thanks Suhas!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    var $item = $('div.mainBodyContentListItem'), //Cache your DOM selectors
        mbcArrowR = $('div.mainBodyContentArrowR'),
        mbcArrowL = $('div.mainBodyContentArrowL'),
        visible = 2, //Set the number of items that will be visible
        index = 0, //Starting index
        endIndex = ($item.length / visible) - 1; //End index
    mbcArrowR.click(function () {
        if (index < endIndex) { //can scroll
            index += 1;
            $item.animate({
                'left': '-=592px'
            });
            mbcArrowL.removeClass('disable');
        }
        mbcArrowR.toggleClass('disable', index >= endIndex);
    });
    mbcArrowL.click(function () {
        if (index > 0) { //can scroll
            index -= 1;
            $item.animate({
                'left': '+=592px'
            });
            mbcArrowR.removeClass('disable');
        }
        mbcArrowL.toggleClass('disable', index <= 0);
    });
});​
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4rKPT/9/